# Python: check if "two" .doc files are the same file?

Tags: python, file

IMAP filtering and searching dictates that my script works as follows: Each night I receive an email with a relevant `.doc` file attached to it. My Python script always selects the last (most recent) email, and does certain operations on that `.doc` file.

All `.doc` files sent daily are named exactly the same.

Issue is: Sometimes the sender neglects to send a new file. The result is that my script does the operation on the wrong file (the one from the day before). If I can somehow check that two files are actually (copies) of the same file, then I can avoid doing the operation.

How is this most easily/effectively achievable in Python?

Answer (score 2):

To compare files binary-wise, the best/quickest way is to use the [`filecmp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filecmp.html) module:

```
>>> import filecmp
>>> filecmp.cmp("first.doc","second.doc",shallow=False)
```

returns `True` if both files share the exact file contents. `shallow` is set to `False` so the file contents are analysed regardless of a difference of date (which you'll have when you extract both files)